# Showing a measure is $\sigma$-finite general case

Tags: measure-theory

[Showing a measure is $\sigma$-finite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2255094/showing-a-measure-is-sigma-finite)

Let $(X_\lambda,B_\lambda,\mu_\lambda)$ be a disjoint collection of measure spaces indexed by $\lambda$. Define $X$ to be the union of all the $X_\lambda$. Define $B=\{S \subseteq X: S \cap X_\lambda \in B_ \lambda\ \forall \lambda\}$. Define $\mu(E)=\sum_\lambda \mu(E \cap X_\lambda)$

Want to show that if all but countable number of  $\mu_\lambda$ are $0$ and the reminder are  $\sigma$-finite, then $\mu$ is  $\sigma$-finite.

The answered question has finite index, how to generalize for arbitrary index?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, without loss of generality, we can suppose that the index is countable, since all $\mu_\lambda$ are $0$, except of a countable subset, say $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots$

If $X_{\lambda_n}=\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A^{\lambda_n}_k$, where $\mu_{\lambda_n}(A_k^{\lambda_n})<\infty$, then the collection of the sets $\{A_k^{\lambda_n}\}_{n,k=1}^\infty$ is a countable family in $B$, every one of these sets has a finite measure $\mu$ and their union is equal to $X$.

**EDIT**: Since OP is confused:

Let $\Lambda$ be the index set. Only countably many measures $\mu_\lambda$ are non-zero, so let's suppose that these measures have indexes $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots$. By assumption, $\mu_{\lambda_n}$ are $\sigma$-finite, so each $X_{\lambda_n}$ can be written as the countable union of measurable sets $A^{\lambda_n}_k$, $k=1,2,\dots$ such that $\mu_{\lambda_n}(A_k^{\lambda_n})<\infty$.

All $X_\lambda$ are disjoint, therefore, for any $k$ and $n$, it is $\mu(A_{k}^{\lambda_n})=\sum_\lambda\mu_\lambda(A_k^{\lambda_n}\cap X_\lambda)=\mu_{\lambda_n}(A_k^{\lambda_n})<\infty$
Now set $F=X\setminus\displaystyle{\bigcup_{n,k=1}^\infty A_k^{\lambda_n}}$. Since for any $n$ it is $X_{\lambda_n}=\displaystyle{\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty A_k^{\lambda_n}}$, we have $\displaystyle{\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty X_{\lambda_n}=\bigcup_{n,k=1}^\infty A_k^{\lambda_n}}$. Hence $F=\displaystyle{\bigcup_{\lambda\in\Lambda\setminus\{\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots\}}X_\lambda}$. Now $\mu(F)=0$ (this is easy).
Hence the family $\{F\}\cup\{A_k^{\lambda_n}:n,k\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is countable, all sets have finite measure $\mu$ and their union is $X$.

Comment: why their union equal $X$ ? and where we have to use disjoint assumption?

Comment: Cause WLOG I assumed that all indexes are $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\dots$. 
If you don't want to assume that, simply adjoin the complement of their union to your family; since we only add 1 extra set the family is countable, the union now is obviously $X$ and all sets are of finite measure.

Comment: @ks1 I have edited my post.

Comment: Thanks for clarification.